# read.zoo is not returning needed date format

Tags: r, zoo, chron

My initial data is in `%y-%m-%d` format...

using the code

```
returnsgamma <- read.zoo(returns, header = TRUE, sep = ",", FUN = as.chron)
```

the zoo file is returning values in the order `%m/%d/%y`

is there anyway to read.zoo and have the order of dates stay as `%y/%m/%d` or `%d/%m/%y`?

Comment: Please read the info at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and in particular we need a complete reproducible example including all library statements and input.  I have provided the input for you this time in the Note at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input shown in the Note at the end we can use the default Date class whose output when rendering defaults to yyyy-mm-dd or use chron with `chron(..., out.format="y-m-d")` which produces yy-mm-dd.

```
library(zoo)

read.csv.zoo(text = Lines, format = "%y-%m-%d")
## 2022-12-01 
##         34 

library(chron)
toChron <- function(x) as.chron(x, out.format = "y-m-d")
read.csv.zoo(text = Lines, FUN = toChron)
## 22-12-01 
##       34
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "date,value
22-12-01,34"
```